# tfs - remove own user without being admin

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-security

Is it possible to remove my user from Visual Studio Online without being admin? I had no contact with companies that I've worked in the past, and their TFS projects keep being displayed when I'm logging into Visual Studio Online / Team Explorer from Visual Studio and I would like to remove my user somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t remove your account if you don’t have the necessary permission, you need to contact them to remove. There are just 5 free users, so I think they are happy to remove unnecessary users.